# PL/PGSQL query is returning only the first row (Supabase)

Tags: sql, postgresql, supabase

I need to query data from a `jobs` table and insert into a `clients` table, into two different columns.

First I grab the customer name to put on `name` column, then I grab the list of unpaid/partially paid jobs of the customer as an array of objects to put on the `open_jobs` column.

The code below works but it only returns the first row.

```sql
do $$
  declare
    x varchar;
    y json;
  begin
    select distinct customer
    into x
    from jobs
    order by customer asc;

    select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
    from (
      select job_location, job_total, paid, invoice_no
      into y
      from jobs
      where customer = x and paid < job_total
      order by invoice_no asc
    )t;

    insert into clients(name, open_jobs)
    values(x, y);
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

I put a link with an image of the query result for reference.

[Query Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kAtx3.png)

Comment: You are looking for [Loop over query results](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-RECORDS-ITERATING).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To elaborate on my comment(not tested):

```
do $$
  declare
    x varchar;
    y json;
  begin
    FOR x IN select distinct customer from jobs
    order by customer asc LOOP

       select array_to_json(array_agg(row_to_json(t)))
       from (
        select job_location, job_total, paid, invoice_no
        into y
        from jobs
        where customer = x and paid < job_total
        order by invoice_no asc
      )t;

      insert into clients(name, open_jobs)
      values(x, y);
   END LOOP;
  end;
$$ language plpgsql;
```

Your original function will only select the first value returned by the customer query. By using the `FOR x IN ... LOOP ... END LOOP` you iterate over all the results of the query.

Comment: It worked, thanks! I just don't understand why I need to iterate over all results. For example, if I write the first select statement with SQL I get all the rows, but if I write the same select statement with PL/PGSQL I get only the first row.

Comment: It is spelled out in the docs [Select Into](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-statements.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-SQL-ONEROW): "If STRICT is not specified in the INTO clause, then target will be set to the first row returned by the command, or to nulls if the command returned no rows. (Note that “the first row” is not well-defined unless you've used ORDER BY.) Any result rows after the first row are discarded."  "If the STRICT option is specified, the command must return exactly one row or a run-time error will be reported ..."